# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. in Chrome

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

Chrome Gives me

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

IE 11 gives me

> Line: 31
>   Error: The stylesheet does not contain a document element.  The stylesheet may be empty, or it may not be a well-formed XML document.

When i press F12:

> "Attribute 'encoding' is invalid on 'xsl:stylesheet'.\r\n"

Actual code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html>
<head>
<script>


function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:23100/ENG_ProcessingTemplate.xsl", false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("http://localhost:23100/ProcessingReport.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("http://localhost:23100/ENG_ProcessingTemplate.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="./ReportViewer.aspx?XSL=1"?>
<report>
<titledata>
<date>5555/5555/5555</date>
<time>08:26:58</time>
</titledata>
<ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.4796.ZZXCV </FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:26:00</ProcTime><Message>6File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>4796 ZZXCV </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.994514555590_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:26:00</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>99451 .</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.3448119.555594_5555_5555_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:59</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>3448119 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.2395.4555541_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:58</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>2395 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.2395.55534_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:57</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>2395 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.15970.Payroll_ _4555587_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:56</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>15970 DDDDX I SERV</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.2395.GDD_455555555_5555_30_5555</ZZXVFileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:56</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>2395 Flavorite Foods GDDS</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.55558507.GDD_4555593_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:54</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>55558507 ZZXV AND</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.55558569.GDD_4555598_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:54</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>55558569 DGSG IDEAS GDDS</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.133383.GDD_4555597_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:54</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>133383 GDSGS</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.55554.GDDS 01_PPD_4555584_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:53</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>55554 GDDS GDDS</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.117437.GDD_4555591_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:52</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>117437 DDDDX SI</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.118796.GDD_4555589_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:52</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>118796 Environmental Sciences </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.116188.Payroll-Weekly_PPD_4555583_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:51</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>116188 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.11.GDGDC_41190_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:50</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>11 A</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.10815555.GDD_4555581_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:49</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>10815555 ZZXV </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.10815555.GDD_4555580_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:48</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>10815555 ZZXV ZZXV</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.106002.6915 &amp; 7115_PPD_4555558_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:47</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>106002 L</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.106418. 555595_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:47</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>106418 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.104685.D_4555599_5555_5555_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:46</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>104685 ZZXV GDDS</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.10394.GDGDC GDD_4555579_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:45</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>10394 ZZXV LI</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.102372.GDD_4555573_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:44</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>102372 TOBAGO REGIONAL HEALTH </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.102398.GDD_41119_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:44</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>102398 P5555 CO</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.10237.GDD_4555562_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:41</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>10237 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.10237.GDD_41164_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:40</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>10237 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.10237.GDD_41160_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:39</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>10237 T</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.100097_4555592_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:38</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>100097 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.102353._4555527_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:38</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>102353 /OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.100035.GDD_4555578_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:37</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>100035 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.100029.GDD_4555586_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:34</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>100029 GDDS</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.100029.GDD_4555588_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:34</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>100029</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.100000.41307_5555_5555_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:33</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>100000 GDDS</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.100029.GDD_4555585_5555_30_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:33</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>100029 </OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>E</IDProcess><FileName>0921.0921.100000._5555_5555_5555</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 08:25:32</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message><OriginID>100000 DDDDX GDDS</OriginID></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>A</IDProcess><FileName>1010090.001.1</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 05:17:23</ProcTime><Message>1082 The payments were generated successfully  </Message></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>D</IDProcess><FileName>_5555555530.txt</FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 05:17:13</ProcTime><Message> File loaded successfully  </Message></ProcessingLog><ProcessingLog><IDProcess>M</IDProcess><FileName></FileName><ProcTime>5555/5555/5555 01:00:26</ProcTime><Message>23 dat  </Message></ProcessingLog>
</report>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
<HTML xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="application/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"></META>
    <BODY>
        <xsl:for-each select="report/titledata">
            <table width="80%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="55%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma">
                            <b>
                                <font size="3">Processing Log</font>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="2">
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="25%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="2">
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="time"/>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <br></br>
        <div width="100%">
            <table width="95%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td width="45%" float="left">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="black">
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="white">
                                        <b>PayBank Manual Process</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>O = ON-US Files Generation</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>N = Not ON-US Files Generation</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>I = Payment Files Collection</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>R = Authorizations and Returns Collection</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>V = Verification Answer File Collection</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>G = Propietary Files Generation</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="45%" float="right">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="black">
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="white">
                                        <b>PayBank Scheduler Process</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>P = ON-US Files Generation</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>A = Not ON-US Files Generation</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>E = Payment Files Collection</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>D = Authorizations and Returns Collection</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>L = Verification Answer File Collection</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>C = Propietary Files Generation</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>T = Automatic Return Report Generation</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr bgcolor="BLACK">
                <td width="5%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Proc</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Date</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>File</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="35%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Error</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Origin</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="8%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Record</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Batch</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="report/ProcessingLog">
                <tr>
                    <td width="5%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="IDProcess"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ProcTime"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%" align="left">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="35%" align="left">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Message"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%" align="left">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="OriginID"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="8%" align="right">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Record"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="7%" align="right">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Batch"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone help me fix this issue.

Comment: Use F12 to open the browser's developer tools and check the console for any errors, in particular whether loading the documents worked. In any case, it appears you want to give your function `loadXMLDoc` a parameter (e.g. `function loadXMLDoc(url) {`) and then use that in the open call with e.g. `xhttp.open('GET', url, false)`.

Comment: XSL File : https://pastebin.com/tfPN8M3i    XML File : https://pastebin.com/XgDZmrcG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal XSLT 1.0 stylesheet would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Report</title>
    </head>        
    <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="report/titledata">
            <table width="80%" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td width="55%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma">
                            <b>
                                <font size="3">Processing Log</font>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="20%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="2">
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="date"/>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="25%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="2">
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="time"/>
                            </b>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <br></br>
        <div width="100%">
            <table width="95%" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td width="45%" float="left">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="black">
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="white">
                                        <b>PayBank Manual Process</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>O = ON-US Files Generation</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>N = Not ON-US Files Generation</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>I = Payment Files Collection</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>R = Authorizations and Returns Collection</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>V = Verification Answer File Collection</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>G = Propietary Files Generation</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td width="45%" float="right">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="black">
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="white">
                                        <b>PayBank Scheduler Process</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>P = ON-US Files Generation</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>A = Not ON-US Files Generation</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>E = Payment Files Collection</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>D = Authorizations and Returns Collection</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>L = Verification Answer File Collection</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td >
                                        <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                            <b>C = Propietary Files Generation</b>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <td >
                                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" >
                                        <b>T = Automatic Return Report Generation</b>
                                    </font>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <br></br>
        <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr bgcolor="BLACK">
                <td width="5%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Proc</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Date</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>File</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="35%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Error</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="15%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Origin</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="8%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Record</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td width="7%" align="center">
                    <font face="tahoma" size="1" color="WHITE">
                        <b>Batch</b>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="report/ProcessingLog">
                <tr>
                    <td width="5%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="IDProcess"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%" align="center">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ProcTime"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%" align="left">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="FileName"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="35%" align="left">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Message"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="15%" align="left">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="OriginID"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="8%" align="right">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Record"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                    <td width="7%" align="right">
                        <font face="tahoma" size="1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Batch"/>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Given that you want to use transformToFragment it would however be better to only return a HTML fragment that fits semantically into the element you `appendChild` to and not a complete document. However, I think browsers will copy with the above.

Make sure you also fix the method to load XML and XSLT to take a parameter, that is, change

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:23100/ENG_ProcessingTemplate.xsl", false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

to

```
function loadXMLDoc(url)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else 
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

Comment: I used the XSL file you put here and I get no errors, I get a template at the top of the screen but I get no data from the xml. I don't know what you mean by your comment. Can you dumb it down for me (i don't know much of XML)

Comment: See the edit, that problem is not about XSLT or XML but about writing a Javascript function taking a parameter you use in its body.

Comment: ok will try.  With IE I get no errors but with Chrome I get warnings  >"The provided value 'msxml-document' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType."

Answer (score 0):

Can you give us examples of your XML/XSL?

This appears to be [client side XSLT processing](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp) which relies on the browser to parse XML. You can always check and debug your XSL/XML syntax... if it's throwing an error it's probably because it's not parsing it correctly, or the browser doesn't natively support whatever version of XSL you're using to transform the XML (unlikely).

Try:

Put the XSL/XML docs in your project and call them as

```
xml = loadXMLDoc("ProcessingReport.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("ENG_ProcessingTemplate.xsl");
```

Without the XML and XSL, it's hard to determine what's actually causing the issue...

Comment: XSL File : https://pastebin.com/tfPN8M3i    XML File : https://pastebin.com/XgDZmrcG